# Element 'item': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument ) when in developer mode

Tags: magento2, database, developer-mode, production-mode

I am getting this error: **Element 'item': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument )** when run command like: **php bin/magento cache:flush.**
I try to get back production mode but still get the same error.

Here log file:

**magento.cron.log**

```
Invalid Document 
Element 'item': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument ).
Line: 197

Element 'item': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument ).
Line: 205

Element 'item': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument ).
Line: 213

Element 'item': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument ).
Line: 225
...........
```

**exception.log**

```
[2023-11-06 01:19:03] main.CRITICAL: Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.

The following modules are outdated:
MagTabe_BaseConfig schema: current version - none, required version - 0.0.2
MagTabe_BaseConfig data: current version - none, required version - 0.0.2 {"report_id":"9226b8a76cca6e9b24733f4116677dce1a095c9b50198110eaec307fac6d7b3b","exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Please upgrade your database: Run \"bin/magento setup:upgrade\" from the Magento root directory.

The following modules are outdated:
MagTabe_BaseConfig schema: current version - none, required version - 0.0.2
MagTabe_BaseConfig data: current version - none, required version - 0.0.2 at /opt/my_website/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php:66)"} []
```

Comment: As per exception log, you need to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` cmd

Comment: @Pawan php bin/magento setup:upgrade not working, i still get error "Element 'item': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument )"

Comment: are you using any custom theme/module ? change theme to luma and try

Comment: i use some custom module third party. right now, i'm in dev mode & cannot access to admin home page.

Answer (score 0):

(solution 1)

So please login phpmyadmin. select your database and find the table name  ="setup_module" Remove MagTabe_BaseConfig so you get an error. after apply upgrade and deploy commands.

```
 php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && php bin/magento c:f
```

(Solution 2)

You can also apply the below query.

```
DELETE FROM setup_module where module = "MagTabe_BaseConfig";
```

After applying the below commands

```
 php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && php bin/magento c:f
```